# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined on Redux thunk action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm new to React, Redux and Thunk and have been following tutorials on the topic, most recently [Building Applications with React and Redux in ES6](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=react-redux-react-router-es6&author=cory-house&name=react-redux-react-router-es6-m11&clip=6&mode=live) on Pluralsight. I've been transposing this tutorial from ES6 to Typescript 3 and React v3 to React v4.

I'm come across a lot of issues that I've been able to resolve following this pattern (most notably anything routing related) but I've come across an issue I can't resolve. From various sources inc [Cannot read property '.then' of undefined when testing async action creators with redux and react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927548/cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined-when-testing-async-action-creators-wit)
 it sounds like I can't have a `.then()` function on a function that returns a void but it's an async function that (is supposed to) return a promise, however the intellisense says otherwise. Code below.

```
saveCourse = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.actions.saveCourse(this.state.course)
        .then(this.setState({ fireRedirect: true }));
}
```

The above code is on my component, `props.actions` are connected to the redux store via `mapStateToProps` and this function is called on the button click. It's the `.then()` on this above function that is erroring. This function calls the action below

```
export const saveCourse = (course: Course) => {
    return (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
        dispatch(beginAjaxCall());
        courseApi.saveCourse(course).then((savedCourse: Course) => {
            course.id ? dispatch(updateCourseSuccess(savedCourse)) :
                dispatch(createCourseSuccess(savedCourse));
        }).catch(error => {
            throw (error);
        });
    }
}
```

The above action is the asyc call, the `.then()` here is not erroring but VS Code says the whole `saveCourse` function returns void.

From the tutorial there really aren't any differences that should make a difference (arrow functions instead of regular etc...) so I'm wondering if there's an obscure change between versions I'm missing but not sure where to look and could be missing something fundamental. Can anyone see why I can't do a `.then()` on the `saveCourse()` function?

Let me know if you need anymore information.

EDIT: the courseApi is just a mock api, code below.

```
import delay from './delay';

const courses = [
{
    id: "react-flux-building-applications",
    title: "Building Applications in React and Flux",
    watchHref: "http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/react-flux-building-applications",
    authorId: "cory-house",
    length: "5:08",
    category: "JavaScript"
},
{
    id: "clean-code",
    title: "Clean Code: Writing Code for Humans",
    watchHref: "http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/writing-clean-code-humans",
    authorId: "cory-house",
    length: "3:10",
    category: "Software Practices"
},
{
    id: "architecture",
    title: "Architecting Applications for the Real World",
    watchHref: "http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/architecting-applications-dotnet",
    authorId: "cory-house",
    length: "2:52",
    category: "Software Architecture"
},
{
    id: "career-reboot-for-developer-mind",
    title: "Becoming an Outlier: Reprogramming the Developer Mind",
    watchHref: "http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/career-reboot-for-developer-mind",
    authorId: "cory-house",
    length: "2:30",
    category: "Career"
},
{
    id: "web-components-shadow-dom",
    title: "Web Component Fundamentals",
    watchHref: "http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/web-components-shadow-dom",
    authorId: "cory-house",
    length: "5:10",
    category: "HTML5"
}
];

function replaceAll(str: any, find: any, replace: any) {
return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

//This would be performed on the server in a real app. Just stubbing in.
const generateId = (course: any) => {
return replaceAll(course.title, ' ', '-');
};

class CourseApi {
static getAllCourses() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(Object.assign([], courses));
        }, delay);
    });
}

static saveCourse(course: any) {
    course = Object.assign({}, course); // to avoid manipulating object         passed in.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Simulate server-side validation
            const minCourseTitleLength = 1;
            if (course.title.length < minCourseTitleLength) {
                reject(`Title must be at least ${minCourseTitleLength} characters.`);
            }

            if (course.id) {
                const existingCourseIndex = courses.findIndex(a => a.id == course.id);
                courses.splice(existingCourseIndex, 1, course);
            } else {
                //Just simulating creation here.
                //The server would generate ids and watchHref's for new courses in a real app.
                //Cloning so copy returned is passed by value rather than by reference.
                course.id = generateId(course);
                course.watchHref = `http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/${course.id}`;
                courses.push(course);
            }

            resolve(course);
        }, delay);
    });
}

static deleteCourse(courseId: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const indexOfCourseToDelete = courses.findIndex(course =>
                course.id == courseId
            );
            courses.splice(indexOfCourseToDelete, 1);
            resolve();
        }, delay);
    });
}
}

export default CourseApi;
```

Comment: Try add return method like `return courseApi.saveCourse(course).then.... ` if that doesn't work, can you show the `courseApi`

Comment: The .then() is failing in the first block of code, sorry didn't make that clear. Editing now and uploading courseApi

Comment: @SGhaleb edited, the .then() is failing in the first block of code, apologies I really didn't make that clear at all

Comment: Did the first solution not fix the problem, what error did it return when you tried it?

Comment: @SGhaleb I tried wrapping the action in a promise like you suggested but got the error "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.". Which is a bugger, that really should've worked. Can you edit thunk's middleware? I have "applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxImmutableStateInvariant())" in my createStore function

Comment: yes you can, like `applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api))` and you can use it like this `function saveCourse (course) { return (dispatch, getState, api) => {// you can use api here}}`

Comment: Can you create an example of your code here https://codesandbox.io/  so its easier to debug, if its not a problem?

Comment: @SGhaleb I'll have to have a play with that, thanks. Strange though because it just works in the tutorial and all that code is the same

Comment: The answer did get it, I missed the return

Comment: Yes, the answer is same as what I put as first comment :)

Comment: Ah crap, yeah I completely missed that! Sorry, that should've been your reputation

Comment: No problem, I only want to help, I put it as a comment not an answer, so wouldn't got the reputation anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that you're not returning the promise in your Action Creator.

Have a look at the example for redux-thunk here:

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

```
function makeASandwichWithSecretSauce(forPerson) {

  // Invert control!
  // Return a function that accepts `dispatch` so we can dispatch later.
  // Thunk middleware knows how to turn thunk async actions into actions.

  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchSecretSauce().then(
      sauce => dispatch(makeASandwich(forPerson, sauce)),
      error => dispatch(apologize('The Sandwich Shop', forPerson, error))
    );
  };
}
```

They're returning the promise generated by `fetchSecretSauce`.

You need to similarly return the promise in your example:

```
export const saveCourse = (course: Course) => {
    return (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
        dispatch(beginAjaxCall());
        return courseApi.saveCourse(course).then((savedCourse: Course) => {
            course.id ? dispatch(updateCourseSuccess(savedCourse)) :
                dispatch(createCourseSuccess(savedCourse));
        }).catch(error => {
            throw (error);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than returning the promise in your Action Creator, you might also want to make sure that in your `mapDispatchToProps`, the corresponding function mapped should be declared `async`. It may `await` the dispatch statement inside.

I ran into a similar issue with exactly the same error message, but other than returning the promise, this is something else that I didn't notice in the first place.